# file format issue with vim 7.4?

Tags: vim

I have this line of code in `.vimrc` :

```
au BufRead *.xlsx exec "echo 'xxx'"
```

And when I open a `.xlsx` file in vim 7.3 ( I know it's weird to open such a file in vim ), it did echo `xxx` to me.
But after I upgraded vim to 7.4 and did the same thing, it didn't echo anything to me now.

I've tested it in several machines getting the same result, so I wonder what feature in 7.4 causes this , and what can I do to make it echo what I want like before?

Comment: Just FYI: You don't need the `:exec` here.

Comment: This should work. I personally have a bunch of BufRead commands that do work. i assume you have a different autocmd that you're worried about? In this particular case I'd try it with echomsg instead of just echo in case the redraw clears it before you can see it, but this is just a toy example, right?

Comment: @Ben Yes. With your advice I do the following: add `au BufRead *.xls,*.xlsx echomsg 'xxx'` to `.vimrc`; in my shell :`echo 'sth' > a.xls`, `echo 'sth' > b.xlsx`. And open them in vim, only `a.xls` echo `xxx` to me... Can you echo sth with a `xlsx` format ?

Comment: I can if I don't load any plugins at all, even the official runtime plugins. But not in my normal config. It looks like the culprit is a BufReadCmd autocmd defined by the pi_zip plugin. It tries to treat xlsx files as zip files. I have no idea why. This plugin can be disabled, but then you can't load zip files the normal way.

Comment: @Ben WOW so great you've figured out the point. Indeed vim treats `xlsx` files as `zip` ones, after I disabled the relative plugin it worked! Though I couldn't make it work for both `xls` and `xlsx` at the same time, what you had told me is more important. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you've figured out the culprit already in the comments (thanks Ben!).

This is caused by version v27 of the *zip plugin* that ships with Vim 7.4. Its change log reads:

> (Jason Spiro) provided a lot of new extensions that are synonyms for .zip

And in fact, the new MS Office file formats (ending with `x`) are all XML-based ZIP files (whereas the previous ones were in a proprietary binary format).

Fortunately, the plugin allows to override the default file extensions that are considered. You can remove the Office ones from the following list and put that into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:let g:zipPlugin_ext= '*.zip,*.jar,*.xpi,*.ja,*.war,*.ear,*.celzip,*.oxt,*.kmz,*.wsz,*.xap,*.docx,*.docm,*.dotx,*.dotm,*.potx,*.potm,*.ppsx,*.ppsm,*.pptx,*.pptm,*.ppam,*.sldx,*.thmx,*.xlam,*.xlsx,*.xlsm,*.xlsb,*.xltx,*.xltm,*.xlam,*.crtx,*.vdw,*.glox,*.gcsx,*.gqsx'
```

Comment: Great answer! I tried to exclude `xlsx` from that list but failed. Thank you!